# Typescript how to implement factory pattern

Tags: typescript

I'm newbie to typescript, and trying to implement kind of factory pattern. Here is the example. I have two methods "getCat" and "getDog", and each of them takes different arguments. And an object "pet" which maps key and corresponding method. I am trying to create a factory "getPet", pass in "type" and corresponding arguments.

But I am not sure how can the "arg" been typed (now it is any), and how to restrict if type is 'cat', the argument is for 'cat' (that has meow method)?

```
interface CatArg {name: string; meow: () => string; }
interface DogArg {name: string; bark: () => string; }


function getCat({name: string, meow}: CatArg) {
    meow();
}

function getDog({name: string, bark}: DogArg) {
    bark();
}

const pet = {
    cat: getCat,
    dog: getDog
};

function playWithPet(type: 'cat' | 'dog', arg: any) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'cat':
            return pet.cat(arg);
        case 'dog':
            return pet.dog(arg);
    }
}

playWithPet('cat', {name: 'Kitty', meow: () => 'dont touch me'});
playWithPet('dog', {name: 'Bella', bark: () => 'play with me'});
```

Comment: you can create a union-type: AnimalArgs = CatArg | DogArg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function overloading like so

```
function playWithPet( type: 'cat', arg: CatArg): void
function playWithPet( type: 'dog', arg: DogArg ): void
function playWithPet( type, arg ) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'cat':
            return pet.cat(arg);
        case 'dog':
            return pet.dog(arg);
    }
}
```

Note: I'm returning void because your `getCat` and `getDog` aren't returning anything. So this function should make it clear nothing is returned, overall I would refactor the code.

Now it will check that the correct object is passed for the second parameter

Another way to do it is this way

```
interface PlayWithPet {
  ( type: 'cat', arg: CatArg ): void
  ( type: 'dog', arg: DogArg ): void
}

const playWithPet: PlayWithPet = ( type, arg ) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'cat':
            return pet.cat(arg);
        case 'dog':
            return pet.dog(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general TypeScript does not encourage such usage but with 3.2+ you can make it work by using tuple types for rest arguments together with discriminated unions:

```
function playWithPet(...args: ['cat', CatArg] | ['dog', DogArg]): void {
  switch (args[0]) {
  case 'cat':
    return pet.cat(args[1]);
  case 'dog':
    return pet.dog(args[1]);
  }
}
```