# How to create object based on mapping key to class in object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

let's assume we have the following situation:

```
class BaseClass {
    // ....some logic
}

class A extends BaseClass{

    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
    someMethodFromInside() {
       // ....some logic
    }
}

class B extends BaseClass {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
    someMethodFromInside() {
       // ....some logic
    }
}
```

And then i would like to choose which object of a class i'm creating, based on some string value, that i'm getting from outside:

```
const someStringFromOutside = 'key1'

const obj: IHandler = {
     'key1': A,
     'key2': B
}

try {
    // here i would like to create object based on value in string choose to pick up class and create 
    // object
    new obj[someStringFromOutside]('somevariable').someMethodFromInside()
} catch(err) {
    ...some error handling
}
```

Because i'm writing in TypeScript i also have to know how to properly type interface in handler:
I was trying to pass some kind ObjectConstructor for value in interface. But it was to generic and typescript display me error.

```
enum HandlerEvents {
    KEY_1 = 'key1',
    KEY_2 = 'key2'
}

interface IHandler {
     [key in HandlerEvents]: .....what should be here ?
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about the typing of `IHandler`. But before that can be answered, I need more details about what this is supposed to do: `obj[someStringFromOutside].someMethodFromInside()` This seems to be calling a function on a type (`A`of `B`) and not an instance of that type.

Comment: It feels like you're trying to make something like this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834383/typescript-how-to-implement-factory-pattern

Comment: `type IHandler = { key1: A, key2: B }` ? No need for `enum`s and mapped types here. You have an inconsistency, though, already outlined above - your methods are not `static`, yet you call it on one of your classes without instantiating it first.

Comment: Yes, i have to make some edit here, i forget about new statement, this methods are not static.

Comment: @Stanislas yes something like there, but with object, because it seems to be looking better with object than with switch case.